# How do i from multiple documents and return the data of a specific field

Tags: mongodb

Here are the multiple document

```
[  
  {
    "Base":[
        {"Female Vitiligo": {
            "occurrence": 18,
            "percentage": 0.44999999999999996,
            "rarity": "EPIC"
        }},
    ]
  },
  {
    "Special":[
        {"Lightning": {
            "occurrence": 168,
            "percentage": 4.2,
            "rarity": "COMMON"
        }},
    ]
  }
]
```

I wanted to return the data in which a field matches the key (e.g. if Base = Female Vitiligo and Special = Lightning return the document below)

```
Base: {
  "occurrence": 18,
  "percentage": 0.44999999999999996,
  "rarity": "EPIC"
},
Special: {
  "occurrence": 168,
  "percentage": 4.2,
  "rarity": "COMMON"
}
```

Comment: Consider refactoring your schema as it has several issues, which makes the query difficult and cumbersome, if not possible. 1. no key to indicate correlation between documents. 2. highly nested structure 3. dynamic column name(i.e. "Female Vitiligo" and "Lightning" as key)

Comment: Yeah that is what i did, the structure was extremely inefficient. Fixed it now, btw.

Comment: Consider posting your solution as an answer so the community can reference it if they encounter similar cases.